# Number of fibres under finite non-flat morphism

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $f:X \to Y$ be a finite, surjective morphism of projective, irreducible varieties over $\mathbb{C}$. We know that there is an open dense subset $U \subseteq Y$ such that every $y \in U$ has exactly $d$ points in its preimage under $f$ where $d$ is the degree of the field extension of the function fields. If $f$ is flat, then the preimage of every point $y \in Y$ consists of at most $d$ points. If $f$ is not flat, then this is not true anymore: Take for example the normalization map of a curve with a double point. But I don't know any example of this phenomenon where $Y$ is a smooth variety. Thus, this is my question:

Can you give me a finite, surjective morphism $f: X \to Y$ of projective, irreducible varieties over $\mathbb{C}$ where $Y$ is smooth such that there is a point $y \in Y$ which has more than $d=[\mathbb{C}(X):\mathbb{C}(Y)]$ points in its preimage under $f$? Hereby $\mathbb{C}(X)$ and $\mathbb{C}(Y)$ are the function fields of $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: No, if $Y$ is smooth (even normal) then every fibre has at most $d$ points. This is in Shafarevich Chapter II.